# Migration in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a site in SharePoint 2010 with approximately 2000 documents distributed in three libraries.
The documents are stored in a complex folder structure so its hard for owner to reach to a document.

Now we have to move these documents in SharePoint 2013 environment in a new and simple design.
Can anyone suggest me which approach I should take for the new design. I have read that folder approach is not a good design.
We will be using CQWP/LVWP to show these doucments so I was thinking to create different columns as metadata properties instead of folders.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I would start here and look into content types, metadata, and planning for search. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262900(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that the approach needs to be considered slightly differently.  In order to fully utilize the new functionality in SharePoint 2013 you cannot just to an in-place upgrade, or a DB-Detach upgrade. And every-time I have seen this, it delays in the inevitable of having to change everything in the future anyway.

I would suggest considering the following:

1.) Setup 2013 with the shiny new functionality in the best practice way then migrate content over using PowerShell or a nice drag-drop migration tool ( Nintex, ShareGate, Metalogix, etc. )

2.) Don't Migrate, and put day forward content in new farm, or migrate non-active content to a archive location in 2013 and move living content manual leveraging new features.

DB-Detach - garbage in garbage out - you take all the bad with all the good.

Comment: This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may use database attach upgrade approach to migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. The database attach upgrade approach includes updating the substance in your environment.The configuration that comes along with SharePoint 2010 will not come along with this approach.

For this methodology we ought to have SharePoint 2013 environment to join the substance databases from SharePoint 2010 environment. While performing this methodology we need to report all the customization amid trail redesign.This data is all that much discriminating to perform the database redesign approach underway environment.

For more information Read these articles:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2012/07/17/upgrading-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step.aspx

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/upgrade-from-sharepoint-2010-to-2013-part1.html

There are also third Party who give the services for [SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 migration](http://www.metaoption.com/Services/Sharepoint-Migration.aspx). I would suggest that go for only Microsoft certified company.

Some are:

http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx

http://www.metaoption.com/Services/Sharepoint-Migration.aspx

http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/